# phpldapadmin not authenticating ldap service

Tags: authentication, ldap, openldap

[image]

I am getting the above error message I pretty sure I am giving correct Login DN and password

[image]
I want to know how can I troubleshoot and inspect what is going wrong where
both the containers are running and phpLdapadmin service is linked .

```
docker run --name phpldapadmin-service --hostname phpldapadmin-service --link ldap-service:ldap-host --env PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=ldap-service --detach osixia/phpldapadmin:latest
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.